# Is there another way to code a loop that selects from one of many with LINQ?

Tags: c#

I have numerous examples of code like this in my application:

```
   foreach (var setting in vm.PTI)
   {
     if (setting.Name == name)
     {
        setting.IsSelected = true;
        App.DB.UpdateIntSetting(SET.Pti, setting.Id);
     }
     else
        setting.IsSelected = false;
   }
```

Loops that run through an array, pick the one row that matches and then set properties in the array.

Although this works well, I am wondering if there are other ways to write this code using LINQ or other. I suspect this might be the best ways but would be interested to get feedback from others as this is something I do maybe 20 times in my code and if there's a better way to do it I would like to try using the better way.

Here is the class that is used:

```
    ParamViewModel[] _pti;
    public ParamViewModel[] PTI
    {
        get => _pti;
        set => SetProperty(ref _pti, value);
    }

public class ParamViewModel: BaseViewModel
{

    int _id;
    public int Id
    {
        get => _id;
        set => SetProperty(ref _id, value);
    }

    string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => SetProperty(ref _name, value);
    }

    bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get => _isSelected;
        set => SetProperty(ref _isSelected, value);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is better than LINQ because you are actually modifying data and LINQ should be used for querying and not manipulating data. 20 times is nothing, that's pretty much what programming is all about: conditions, loops etc.

Comment: Having said that, you can query like this: `vm.PTI.Where(x => x.Name == name);` and then loop them and do the part in your `if` condition. Then another query like this: `vm.PTI.Where(x => x.Name != name);` and loop them and do the part in the `else` part. I still think what you have is better.

Comment: I would agree with CodingYoshi. Its better this way than in linq. Even both are enumerating the collection. I basic choice i do if i'm querying something or transforming i will use linq or something like this can stay in `foreach`.
Always strive for readability & maintainability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular case you can write extension method:

```
    public static void ModifyCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Predicate<T> selectedPredicate,Action<T> selectedAction, Action<T> othersAction=null)
    {
        if (selectedPredicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selectedPredicate));
        if (selectedAction == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selectedAction));
        foreach (var element in source)
        {
            if (selectedPredicate(element))
            {
                selectedAction(element);
            }
            else
            {
                othersAction?.Invoke(element);                    
            }
        }
    }
```

How to use it:

```
PTI.ModifyCollection(
      selectedPredicate:(s) => s.Name == name,
      selectedAction:(s) => 
           { 
             s.IsSelected = true; 
             App.DB.UpdateIntSetting(SET.Pti, setting.Id); 
           },
      othersAction:(s) => s.IsSelected = false);
```

You can go further and specify [constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) to T. 'where T is INamed' and put predicate code inside extension method.

You can write your own extension method:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
    foreach (var element in source)
    {
        action(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: @CodingYoshi it just a matter of convenience. You can't for example do that collection.Where(...).foreach(var c in collection){}; But with this extension you can do that collection.Where(...).ForEach((e)=>dosomething);

Comment: @CodingYoshi Why do you use Linq if foreach and for loop existed long before that?

Comment: @CodingYoshi from that thread: 
1. Type checking: foreach is done at runtime, ForEach() is at compile time (Big Plus!)
2. The syntax to call a delegate is indeed much simpler: objects.ForEach(DoSomething);
3. ForEach() could be chained

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say, I am saying `ForEach` is already available as an extension method so why are you suggesting to create something which already exists?

Comment: @CodingYoshi not sure what you mean, try this:  IEnumerable<string> words = new string[] { "a","b"};  words.ForEach((s)=>Console.WriteLine(s));;

Comment: Try `words.ToList().ForEach` ;)

Comment: @CodingYoshi just confirm that it does not exist. : ) And my extension method makes sense.

Comment: +1 You can argue whether this extension method should be this or that way. However, I like the idea of implementing once and reuse. We do not know the actual repetitive pattern. Probably `IsSelected ` is always handled the same. It could be part of this method. Probably selecting by `Name` is always the same. We don't know.

Comment: @CodingYoshi There is no such method for IEnumerable<T>. There is a method for List<T>, but it does not make sense to Convert collection to List to get some method. ToList() will create a copy for value types and structs, so it could be expensive operation.

Comment: @Access Denied Can you give an example of an extension method that I could use for this case.  I did add some more details on the array that I am using.

Comment: @Alan2 Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the setting first with LINQ, then set it.

```
var setting = vm.PTI.FirstOrDefault( s => s.Name == name );
if (setting != null)
{
    setting.IsSelected = true;
    App.DBUpdateIntSetting(SET.Pti, setting.Id);
}
```

Comment: How about else?

Comment: A bool field is defaulted to false

Comment: A better way will be via First rather than Where, unless there can be multiple matching records. First will return as soon as the 1st match is found and 2nd will continue till the end

Comment: This is not correct because it is only affecting the first item and it is also missing the `else` part.

Comment: There will be one (maybe different) setting.IsSelected will be true before this runs.